# Html input tag with server side resource string

Tags: asp.net, html, resources, server-side

I have an input button on an ASP.NET form, but I want the text displayed to come from a server side resource file.

The following syntax fails, and I can't enclose it in a literal because the input tag cannot contain any other tags:

```
 <input id="btnX" type="button" disabled="disabled" value='<%$Resources:res,Button.Text%>' />
```

Any possible solutions?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about <%= function %> ?

Comment: I've tried it, and by the look of things, it gets confused if there is a quote or equals sign in the resource object. Could work if we're careful though - thanks

Comment: As I recall intellisense doesn't like it much

Comment: I just tested
<input id="btnX" type="button" disabled="disabled" value="<%= Generated String%>" />
It appears to work on my Test Server

Answer (score 6):

I would think apocalypse's answer should work:

```
<%= GetLocalResourceObject("Button.Text") %>
```

or

```
<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("res", "Button.Text") %>
```

Answer (score 5):

It will work if you add `runat="server"` to the input tag.

Comment: adding runat would alter his generated client id for the control; I'm guessing that's trying to be avoided

Comment: Not if you're setting `ClientIDMode` to `Static`